# Is there a HTML templating engine for Google App Engine (in Java)?

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, template-engine, templating

Looking for something simple (like Smarty for PHP or erb in Rails), but that will allow nesting templates inside each other. Does App Engine have anything built-in, or will I need to look into something separate (like Velocity?)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the templating engine for creating HTML pages (or other content that you are sending to the user directly), you could use JSP, I suppose.

JSP support comes built-in with App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at Velocity, you may also want to consider [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/). It has a more complex, but correspondingly richer, markup language than Apache Velocity.

Comment: I wasn't really "looking" at Velocity... Google just suggested it. I'll take a gander at Freemaker, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also possibly worth noting, I'm a total Java noob, so I haven't done ANY web programming with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Rythm](http://rythmengine.com) is a fast, feature rich and developer friendly template engine. The site itself is running on GAE

Answer (score 0):

My lightweight template engine, [Chunk Templates](http://www.x5software.com/chunk), will run in Google App Engine.

Chunk features includes, branching, looping, and macros, and has a simpler `{$tag}` syntax than Velocity and Freemarker.

Plenty of built-in [tag filters](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/wiki/Chunk_Tag_Filters) too, eg:

```
{% $value|sprintf(%.02f) %}

{% $value|onempty("N/A") %}
```